# How to implement custom buttons into individual posts?

Tags: facebook, buttons

Is there any way that I can code custom buttons for liking, sharing, and tweeting on individual posts on wordpress. If so, how would I link the like button to like the post on Facebook and how would I link the share and tweet buttons.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. You need to be more specific with your issue. Where is your code and where are you stuck. File an [edit] and provide your current code and point out **exactly** where your code is failing you. Thnk you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to add custom sharing buttons (just place this code where you want your sharing buttons to be displayed):

```
<?php
$twitter_username = 'your_twitter_username';
$shortURL = esc_url(get_permalink());
$shortTitle = esc_attr(get_the_title());
$imgURL = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
$twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$shortTitle.'&amp;url='.$shortURL.'&amp;via='.$twitter_username;
$facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$shortURL;
$googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$shortURL; 
$pinURL = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$shortURL.'&media='.$imgURL.'&description='.$shortTitle;
?>

<a class="facebook-btn" href="<?php echo $facebookURL; ?>" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $facebookURL; ?>', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=no,width=500,height=400');return true">Share on Facebook</a>
<a class="google-btn" href="<?php echo $googleURL; ?>" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $googleURL; ?>', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=no,width=500,height=400');return true">Share on Google Plus</a>
<a class="twitter-btn" href="<?php echo $twitterURL; ?>" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $twitterURL; ?>', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=no,width=500,height=300');return true">Tweet on Twitter</a>
<a class="pinterest-btn" href="<?php echo $pinURL; ?>" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $pinURL; ?>', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=no,width=700,height=500');return true">Pin on Pinterest</a>
```

Now what you need to do is to add some style to these classes:

```
.facebook-btn

.google-btn

.twitter-btn

.pinterest-btn
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: You should escape the title and the URLs. Both are not safe!

Comment: @toscho It is correct like this? I really don't know how to escape the title and the URLs... and I don't know why I should do this either...

Comment: The title can contain markup, even a script. You could also use `the_title_attribute([ 'echo'=>false])` for that. The image URL should be escaped too.